# Equation: $2\sqrt{1-x}-\sqrt{1+x}+\sqrt{1-x^2}=3-x$

Tags: calculus

$2\sqrt{1-x}-\sqrt{1+x}+\sqrt{1-x^2}=3-x$

Could someone help me solve this problem?

Comment: ^Is it? When I plug in $x = 0$, I got $2 = 3$.

Comment: @SherlockHolmes At $x=0$, we get $2-1+1=3-0\implies 2=3$

Comment: Are complex solutions being considered?

Comment: $S=\phi$, but i cant prove that :((

Comment: ^What is $S$ in this problem?

Comment: @DavidH It was a joke.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Assuming that we are restricted to only real square roots:

Substitute $a = \sqrt{1-x}$ and $b = \sqrt{1+x}$ to get $2a-b+ab = 2+a^2$

Solving for $b$ gives us $b = a-1+\dfrac{1}{a-1}$.

Since $b$ must be non-negative, $a-1$ must be positive. Then, by AM-GM, we get that $b \ge 2$.

However, $b = \sqrt{1+x} \ge 2$ iff $x \ge 3$, which makes $\sqrt{1-x}$ imaginary.

Hence, there are no real solutions.

Comment: Its beautiful, Thanks you :D